# How to create a map like ‘hypoxia’ in Godot4 by procedural generation?

Tags: 2d-games, gdscript, godot4

I want to make a game such like 'hypoxia', but i wonder like know how to do that?
[blocks sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMDQX.png)

as the pic,

1. them have difference boder between the difference elements
2. They also express continuity, even if only exists on the diagonal

I tried drawing different blocks and using tileMap to assemble them,
but them was sander block.

Please let me know what i should to do, including the game art.

thanks a lots

```
extends Node2D

var noise
var map_size = Vector2(100,100)
var dirt = 5
var gold = 3

# Called when the node enters the scene tree for the first time.
func _ready():
    randomize()
    noise = FastNoiseLite.new()
    noise.set_noise_type(FastNoiseLite.NoiseType.TYPE_PERLIN)
    noise.seed = randi()
    make_chuck()

func make_chuck():
    var dirt_cells = []
    var gold_cells = []
    for x in map_size.x:
        for y in map_size.y:
            var block = noise.get_noise_2d(x,y) * 100
            if  gold < block && block < dirt:
                print(block)
                dirt_cells.append(Vector2i(x,y))
            if block < gold:
                print(block)
                gold_cells.append(Vector2i(x,y))
    $cv.set_cells_terrain_connect(0,dirt_cells,0,0) ##dirt
    $cv.set_cells_terrain_connect(0,gold_cells,1,0) ##gold
```